# Eclipse Debugging with tomcat Jdwp port setting

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, debugging, jakarta-ee

One one project scenario is:-

I know how to set the jvm argument for jdwp in ant. I set the following values in ant build file for tomcat jvm arguments

here "suspend = y" means remote jvm will suspend until debugger is not attached. This is happening. virtual machine suspends and I start eclipse debugger then remote jvm starts

But for my another project I start the tomcat server from eclipse server view. Here I start the eclipse in debug mode using eclipse. and virtual machine start in debug mode and remote machine suspended.

Now My question is where these jvm argument(for remote debugging) mentioned ? when i start server in debugging mode using the eclipse. Is eclipse passing the arguments?

what I did for this I checked the catlina.sh and bat file to see the configuration... i see some configuration in catilina.sh file below...

```
if [ "$1" = "jpda" ] ; then
  if [ -z "$JPDA_TRANSPORT" ]; then
    JPDA_TRANSPORT="dt_socket"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_ADDRESS" ]; then
    JPDA_ADDRESS="6666"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_SUSPEND" ]; then
    JPDA_SUSPEND="n"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_OPTS" ]; then
    JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=$JPDA_TRANSPORT,address=$JPDA_ADDRESS,server=y,suspend=$JPDA_SUSPEND"
  fi
  CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS $JPDA_OPTS"
  shift
fi
```

if this script is controlling when in this script suspend value is 'n' as above mentioned by  suspend=$JPDA_SUSPEND" and  JPDA_SUSPEND="n"

please tell me where these option are available for customization?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to start eclipse in debug mode, all it needs is starting Tomcat in your server view in debug mode with the bug icon. Assuming the same code is deployed as visible in your project, then you can set breakpoints and step through your code.

In case you want to do the same with a remote Tomcat, then you have to manually add the debug settings in the start script and connect with a Remote Java Application runtime configuration.